# does sharepoint online supports any data analytics tools/application?

Tags: sharepoint-online, data, analytics

does sharepoint online supports any data analytics tools or application that I can look into? I know that sharepoint supports web-analytics and there's power BI. However, power BI seems to support more on data visualization. I'm looking at something that supports more on the data site. Maybe that works like [IBM SPSS Modeler](https://www.ibm.com/bs-en/marketplace/spss-modeler#product-header-top).

Trying to find a way that helps sharepoint user to analyse their documents saved in sharepoint library. For example analyse the data in excel/pdf/word doc, it could be any form. Textual, number, color code or even cells that have been highlighted.

Any suggestion and help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try looking into azure. You can get 1 year free or if your a developer you would have an msdn licence which gives you it all for free under your cal.

once you have azure you can then create any big data servers hosted on azure like hadoop, spark, HD insight, tableau or just use bog standard SQL.

my personal opinion is that IBM SPSS Modeler, is pretty much the same as BI or tableau. If your looking for big data (predicting future based off past with massive amounts of data) then above is deffo what you need. Looking at list data on sharepoint 9/10 tableau or BI are the market leaders.

you need to be more specific in what you mean by "analyse data on saved documents", needed to know to determine what 3rd party tool is best (if possible) or if a custom solution is better.

i did something similar for a company i worked for. Didn't want to spend money and didnt want another server (hosted in azure) to maintain. They wanted to see all checked out files and associated meta data. Deleted files, missing meta data ect.... only solution was a custom solution that's based on JavaScript to query and search services.

Comment: Thanks for the info. For mine it will not be able to apply to the company, probably for department usage. Was looking into Power BI but the company already remove the application for their application list.

Comment: thats a shame. you do know that BI is free and you could sign up to it? would be strange for a company just to give up somthing that is free :) , login to 365 unless the company doesnt allow it, for the application ok but for the online version should be ok. also 9/10 i find that people who use BI dont/know how to use it properly to get the data that they need. like using odata/rest to get your lists and data and how to manipulate the data properly. BI doesn't have to be visual too ;). otherwise your going to find it hard pressed to find somthing useful OOTB so as noted Azure or custom code

Comment: Yap, I found it strange it too. They disable the access to the application. I'm looking into Power Pivot, Power View and Power Query right now :)

Comment: lol going old school ;) , would get the job done though, that with odata from sharepoint!

Comment: Still accepted, it is a solution to this problem